# JQuery Mobile link to external page in other domain - how do I get back?

Tags: jquery-mobile, back-button

JQuery Mobile question: I am linking to an external page in another domain but I want the user to be able to come back. The best thing I suppose would be to open another browser instance for the external page. The second best thing would be to have a back button in the browser. Android has a hardware back button which works OK but what about iOS and other platforms? Has anyone been able to do this, and how?
Thanks to all in advance.
--Alex

Comment: Depending on your needs and whether the external web site allows itself to run in frames, you could launch a dialog page which includes an iframe pointing at the external web site, then include a regular back button in the dialog header: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hzTfS/7/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It didn't work at first but then I realized that the URL in your example ended with a slash, and that made all the difference.